# Cannot find the package in python-poetry and it listed 9 at most

Tags: python-poetry

The old project was build by Conda and I need to migrate it to using poetry.

One can use `Poetry Init` command to set up the toml configuration file. `sphinx` library was listed in the old Conda enviroment.yml file. And I need to add it by using poetry

In the step of adding packages, when I search `sphinx` there is only 9 candidates, in fact there are always 9 candidates. And there is no `sphinx` listed (see below) but when I put the name my self as it mentioned ,**or the complete package name if it is not listed**, I got **the Value "sphinx" is invalid** error

```
Enter package # to add, or the complete package name if it is not listed:
 [0] sphinx-pyreverse
 [1] sphinx-charts
 [2] sphinx-javalink
 [3] sphinx-automodapi
 [4] sphinx-hoverxref
 [5] sphinx-runner
 [6] sphinx-jsondomain
 [7] pytest-sphinx
 [8] sphinx-tagtoctree
 [9] sphinx-patchqueue
 >
```

And `poetry add sphinx` command is not working as well and gives me the SolverProblemError message

And idea how to solve this?

Comment: Which version of poetry do you use? I'm not able to reproduce it.

Comment: 3.9 I think I fund the reason, when I use python 3.7 the problem is solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment the poetry is written by python 3.7 but I am using python 3.9. When using the python 3.7 all issues were off